# Smallest qudit error correcting/detecting codes

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code

Consider encoding a qubit into $n$ qubits. It is well known that the smallest error detecting code is in $n=4$ qubits and the smallest error correcting code is in $n=5$ qubits.

Is there a similar result for qudits? If we encode a qudit into $n$ qudits, are there any results on the smallest $n$ we need in order to detect or correct a single qudit error?

Comment: ((3,1,2)) qutrit code https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/stab_3_1_2#:~:text=Holographic%20code%20%E2%80%94%20Three%2Dqutrit%20code,smallest%20nontrivial%20quantum%20MDS%20code. is lower bound for $ d=2 $ and $ n=3 $ and qutrits.